# draw a randomly fluctuating function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wanted to draw the following

[image: Random texture]

My approach is to start from a sin^2 and then change the frequency with rand. My solution up to now looks like

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [
declare function={fy(\x)=sin(\x+rand*100)^2;}
]

\begin{axis} [
xmin=-720, xmax=720,
width=10cm, height=10cm,
tick style=black,
clip mode=individual,
x axis line style={opacity=0},
y axis line style={opacity=0},
ticks=none
]

\addplot [
ultra thick,
smooth,
tension=1,
samples=30,
domain=-720:720
] {fy(x)};

\draw[latex-latex, xshift=-0.5cm] ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) -- ({rel    axis cs:0,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) node[left, pos=0.5] {$h$};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Playing with the parameters: tension, factor of rand, samples I already get closer to the desired output, but if someone has another idea...
On top of that is there a way to scale ymax and ymin such that it fits the rand results? I dont know why but sometimes I get values for sine that are greater than 1 and smaller than 0. I don't really understand why. The current output is

[image: profile]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Could you describe in a little more detail what exactly you're looking for? The title "Draw a random function" is very broad, and you seem to have a more specific idea of what you want your function to look like. From the image you posted, it seems like you want the amplitude of the random fluctuations to be similar, but the wavelength should vary more strongly?

Comment: this guide shows you how to do some basic plotting... [minimal tikz](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf).  From what you're asking I think you can combine a few different examples and get everything you want. There's also [TEXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/plots/) that contains much more detailed examples.

Comment: Actually the picture that I've attached is pretty much what I was thinking about drawing, but well I messed up the description. After all it would be piecewise-stiching of sines of same amplitude for different wavelengths. I will produce the MWE tonight :), thought there was maybe a standard function that could have been called.

Comment: chech out the `rand` function of tikz along with the `smooth` option. Your first figure would make me try a function like `sin(x+ rand)^2`

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a [frequency modulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation), so the frequency of the function should vary over the domain. Here's an example that chooses different values each time, but keeps those constant for the whole plot.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\amplitudefluctuationfrequency}{2+rnd}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\amplitudefluctuationamplitude}{0.1+rand*0.4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\frequencyfluctuation}{0.5+rand*0.05}

\begin{tikzpicture} [
declare function={fy(\x)=(1+sin(\x*\amplitudefluctuationfrequency)*\amplitudefluctuationamplitude)*sin(\x*1.47*(cos(\x*\frequencyfluctuation)*0.5+1.5));}
]

\begin{axis} [
xmin=-720, xmax=720,
width=10cm, height=10cm,
tick style=black,
clip mode=individual,
x axis line style={opacity=0},
y axis line style={opacity=0},
ticks=none
]

\addplot [
ultra thick,
smooth,
tension=1,
samples=1440,
domain=-720:720
] {fy(x)};

\draw[latex-latex, xshift=-0.5cm] ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) -- ({rel    axis cs:0,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) node[left, pos=0.5] {$h$};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Sample Output

[image]

Comment: that already looks great. Any idea how to adjust the latex-latex h to the global minimum/maximum?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Please clarify and/or rephrase?

Comment: to the left there is the double-arrow denoted by h. But if you compare to the graph h doesn't denote anything. It should reach until maximum & minimum value though.